# Submenu setup with jquery and effect 'fold'

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get open submenu with a jquery effect *fold*, the problem is if a user do a "hover effect" to fast then the menu stay open, how can i avoid this, my jquery code is:

```
$('ul.mainmenu li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children('ul').show('fold', 570);
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('ul').hide('fold', 500);
    }
);
```

My JsFiddle link is: http://jsfiddle.net/9wkBf/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9wkBf/15/ Check this, it might be a workaround

Comment: @ShaunakD nice shoot! absolutely should be accepted as right answer

Comment: @Infer-On sadly, it won't be applicable to other menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wkBf/15/)**

The reason behind that problem is, The first event `$(this).children('ul').show('fold', 570);` is queued and until it completes, the second animation will not start.

The following snippet can be a workaround

```
$('ul.mainmenu > li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children('ul').show('fold', 570);
    }, function() {
        $('ul:not(.mainmenu)').hide('fold', 500);

    }
);
```

***Important Note** : This will work only for current scenario.